# navbar-brand-center collapsed menu works in firefox but not chrome or ios

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

When my navbar collapses the drop menu does not work on click when using chrome or ios, although it works in Firefox. 
See www.ankordivelights.com. Notice that the menu items also overlap the logo in the center, can this be prevented.
I have listed the code for the navbar below. If anyone can see a problem with the html please let me know.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE]><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html dir="ltr" lang="en" class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html dir="ltr" lang="en" class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Your Store</title>
<base href="http://ankordivelights.com/" />
<meta name="description" content="My Store" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<link href="http://ankordivelights.com/image/catalog/cart.png" rel="icon" />
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,300,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="catalog/view/theme/mycustomtheme/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<header>




        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-brand-centered">
                <span class="button-label">Menu</span>
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered" href="index.php">
              <image id ="brand-image" src="image/logo.png"/>
              </a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-brand-centered">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">


                    <li><a href="#">VIDEO LIGHTS </a></li>                                   
             <li><a href="#">LIGHTING SYSTEMS</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">HANDHELDS</a></li>    



              </ul>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                 <li><a href="#">UMBILICALS</a></li>          
                <li><a href="#">ACCESSORIES</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://localhost/shop/index.php?route=product/category&path=33">TEST CENTRES</a></li>


              </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the styling on your site.  You have a div of class `.my_twin_container` that has a property set to `margin-top: -530px !important`.  This is causing that div which appears to be used more for center page content to be overlapping your `header` tag.  The styling for this site needs to be reworked to not use such a large negative margin which is creating an undesirable overlapping of elements.  The button for the collapsed menu is not working because it cannot be clicked with content overlapping it.